# Returning BSonDocuments from a WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf, mongodb, wcf-data-services, odata

I am using the official MongoDB C# driver and I am trying to find a way to deserialize a BSonDocument into a class.

The thing is that I want this to be generic (without having to create manually beforehand).
I need to do this because I am building a WCF data service with a ServiceOperation that will return documents in my mongo database. The documents returned can be anything so they won't necessarily fit a certain class structure.

Unfortunately, I cannot just return a list of BSonDocuments as my service complains that

```
The type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument' is not a complex type or an entity type.
```

Any of you faced a similar problem? If so what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your BsonDocument to a JSON string and return that and then parse it back at  the receiving end.

At the server:

```
var json = document.ToJson();
return json;
```

At the client:

```
var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);
```

Comment: Yeah that's a valid alternative. I'll go with this, thanks for the suggestion.